# Stack level too Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack

am fairly new to ruby so am not too sure what
going wrong. Am getting an error saying 
"stack level too deep" am trying to register a 
new user

here is my code:

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @user = User.new
  end

def create
  @user = User.new(params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

private

  def params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :secondName, :activated, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

Users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :activated
  validates_presence_of :firstName
  validates_presence_of :secondName
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Full Error is :

> SystemStackError in UsersController#create
>   stack level too deep

Comment: Please post the entire error.

Comment: Post your user.rb as well. There's probably a problem with your relationships.

Comment: i dont know if the order in which they are placed in the `params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :secondName, :activated, :email, :password)` matters or not

Comment: The order of parameters in your sanitizer doesn't matter -- they just need to be there. This isn't causing your problem, but you need to remove the line attr_accessor :password from user.rb or it will make your password blank because you're using Rails 4 strong params.

Comment: `params.permit`'s parameter order doesn't matter.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa why was it saying stack level too deep, but that error has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params` method needs to be named something other than `params`, such as `safe_params`. Otherwise you're calling itself when you go `params.require` on the very next line.

The `params.require` is accessing a method called `params` that comes from within Rails. The `params` method you just `def`'d is overriding the Rails `params` method.

Clarity edit: This is what it should look like:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(safe_params)
  ...
end

def safe_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :secondName, :activated, :email, :password)
end
```

Comment: i changed the name and it seems to have gotten rid of that error but now its saying `undefined local variable or method `safe_params' for #<UsersController:0x3b10630>`  the error is on this line  `safe_params.require(:user).permit(:firstName, :secondName, :activated, :email, :password)`

Comment: @Roland You changed the wrong params. Your *method* needs to be called safe_params, whereas safe_params.require needs to be changed back to params.require.

Comment: By the way, the "convention" is to name your method `user_params`.